# The Explanation of these steps

Tags: derivatives, tangent-spaces

I was following a lecture on Tangent Spaces, where I find expressions as:

$$(f\circ\gamma\circ\mu)'(0) = (f\circ\gamma)'(\mu(0)).\mu'$$

And in some other place, I find:

$$((f\circ x^{-1})\circ(x\circ\sigma))'(0) = (x\circ\sigma)^{i'}(0).(\partial_{i}(f\circ x^{-1}))(x(\sigma(0))) $$

Now, I am new to Undergraduate Analysis, and cannot understand how the derivative of the above mentioned operators are happening. So can anyone please explain me how these steps come about, or, provide me with some materials to study these.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For second I need little more info, but look likes it's same chain rule for multiple variables - can you specify something about given functions?

Comment: can you please suggest me any topic where I can read these in details please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case - from here you can take brief imagination, for study, I think, will be good to find book on most close language for you. Is English ok?

Comment: No its fine, thanks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is simple chain rule using for $f\circ\gamma$ and $\mu$.
Second look likes same chain rule for multiple variables: if rewrite as
$$((f\circ x^{-1})\circ(x\circ\sigma))'(0) = \sum_{i}(\partial_{i}(f\circ x^{-1}))(x(\sigma(0)))(x\circ\sigma)^{i'}(0).$$

Comment: i guessed that, but what about the second one?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: thanks. it really helped me!